# Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'esnext'

Tags: angular, vscode-debugger

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am not able to find what is the error:

```
Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'esnext'
```

Comment: A newer version as of June 2023 of the error ts(6046) is `error TS6046: Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'node12', 'nodenext'.`

Answer (score 6):

It is telling you that the value for  `"module": "es2020"` is invalid and that it needs to be one of the values it mentions. Since your `target` is set to `es2015`, perhaps setting `"module": "es2015"` would fix your issue

Comment: pleasure. Don't forget to accept answers that solved your issue :-)

Comment: @Micah can you share your exact error and your code in a separate question?

Comment: I meant to update this, I was experiencing a very laggy IDE issue. So it was solving it but not rendering accordingly for several minutes. Thank you for the follow up.